# Lemonade as a base for steak marinade

Tags: steak, marinade, lemonade

I have marinaded steaks in the past with acidic juices, usually including orange juice.  The acidity seems to help with the tenderization of the meet and the slight sweetness in addition with salt and spices makes for a great flavor combination.

Is it possible to use lemonade as a base for a marinade? If possible what is an ideal recipe for a decent cut of beef?

Comment: A quick google indicates it is done, but is not common. Here was one http://www.cooks.com/recipe/6y35y9uq/lemonade-marinade-for-beef-chicken-or-pork.html

Comment: I've seen meat marinated in Coke at some Mexican restaurants; a quick web search will turn up plenty of hits.

Comment: One thing to watch out for is that lemonade can legally made out of anything. It doesn't need to made with lemon juice, many cheap bottled lemonades are mostly apple, grape or pear juice, so it may not be acidic as you hope. Instant lemonade mixes have no juice at all though they use normally use fair bit of citric acid and ascorbic acid.

Answer (score 1):

I use a basic marinade of lemon juice (from the squeeze plastic lemon, not fresh), brown sugar, Dale's sauce and Worcestershire sauce, so it would be similar to a lemonade base (lemon juice and sugar)

The lemon juice tenderizes and cuts the salt of the last two ingredients. Brown sugar also cuts the salt and gives it "caramel like" coloring. The Dale's and Worcestershire sauces just have nice flavor profiles when combined on any red meat.

I do the same for chicken but substitute Teriyaki sauce for the Worcestershire.